# What does $E(X \leq x)$ represent in this definition of a random variable?

Tags: probability

I'm not exactly sure what $E(X\leq x)$ represents in the following definition:

"A random variable of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the sets $E(X \leq x)$= $\{\omega:X(\omega) \leq x\} \in \mathbb{F}$ $,\space\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$"

where $\mathbb{F}$ is the set of all possible events.

1) my initial guess is that it's the union of all the events such that $X\leq $ hence why it's equal to $\{\omega:X(\omega) \leq x\}$. However this hasn't been stated explicitly and I'd just like to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That letter "$E\,$" in there is very old-fashioned.  It's use probably* went out of style around 1950.  I'm guessing it is for the French word "Ensemble" which is "Set" in English.

Long ago, a "random variable  $X$" was something in probability theory, but the function $X$ from a sample space $\Omega$ to the reals was merely a "model" for probability in real analysis, not the actual thing.  So write the letter $E$ to map from the "event" $(X \le x)$, which is something in the probability world, into a set $\{\omega : X(\omega) \le x\}$, which is something in the real analysis world.  They would not have used the same letter $X$ for both of them, either.

Nowadays, we do not make that distinction so completely.

> * no pun intended

Answer (score 0):

The set $E(X\leqslant  c)$ is just an event, that is, an element of $\Bbb F $. Now note that
$$
E(X\leqslant c):=\{\omega \in\Omega :X(\omega )\leqslant c\}=X^{-1}((-\infty ,c])
$$
Then the condition
$$
\{\omega \in\Omega :X(\omega )\leqslant c\}\in \Bbb F ,\quad \forall c\in \Bbb R 
$$
just means that $X$ is $\Bbb P $-measurable. We need $X$ measurable to induce a Borel measure $\mu _X$ in $\Bbb R $ defined by
$$
\mu _X(A):=\Bbb P (X^{-1}(A))\quad \text{ for any Borel set }A\subset \Bbb R 
$$
The measure $\mu _X$ is generally named as **the distribution of $X$**, what induces the **distribution function**
$$
F_X(c):=\mu _X((-\infty ,c])
$$